# What if callback() is not executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have a kind of a simple question but couldn't find any answer on the web.

In a javascript function with a callback in its parameters, *must* always have a `callback()` inside? Could be any performance issue if the `callback()` is only executed sometimes?

```
function do_this(param1, callback) {
    param1.forEach(function(param) {
       io.sockets.connected[param].emit('do this', function(res) {
           if (res) callback();
       });
    });
}
```

Note that in this code, the `callback()` should not always be called. Any potential performance issue in running this as many callings to function `do_this()` won't return a callback?

Comment: Performance issue? If there's a control flow that depends on `callback` being executed, then it'll stall, but no, no performance issues. It just seems like a really inconsistent function signature considering that it looks like `callback` could be executed 0, or several times depending on certain factors.

Comment: passing a parameter won't impact your performance at all. Only thing that will happen is there are additional bytes used while passing function parameters. 
So you are good to go !

Answer (score 1):

No, issues only on logic.

If callback will not be called, it means that your program will not be able to know what happen with it's call, but about performance, in your sample, after you get the emit callback, and not call your callback, function will lost last link and will be a food for trash collector, so in fact it will be forgotten and no formal performance impact.

But better still use some signals of result, like when we have a rule - if function returns something in condition it should return something other without condition, just to understand data flow better.

Use `Promises` and better always resolve/reject them, otherwise you will not be able to be sure of program state.

So finally  - it will work but better to avoid such patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your replies.

I finally implemented the code using async library just to emit a `callback` right at the end of the `for..loop`, but I was curious whether the other way had implicated any performance penalty.